# Batch Command to Stop Hidden Audio Track

Tags: batch-file, audio, vbscript, hidden

I am making a game using batch files, and I am very new to coding. I wanted to use batch commands to play hidden audio files for music. I then found this line of code:

```
    '@echo off
    set "file=track12.mp3"
    ( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
      echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
      echo Sound.Controls.play
      echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
      echo wscript.sleep 100
      echo loop
      echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000)         >sound.vbs
    start /min sound.vbs'
```

It worked perfectly fine. However, I need to add a command to actually STOP the hidden audio file at a certain point, like when you go into another room. Is it possible to do this, or do I need to scrap this piece of code and look for something else?

Comment: ...is it not just `Sound.Controls.Stop`?

Answer (score 1):

With a batch file you can do something like that :

```
@echo off
Title Listen to the music with batch and vbscript
mode con cols=60 lines=3 & color 9E
echo.
Echo           To stop the music just close this window 
set "file=http://www.chocradios.ch/djbuzzradio_windows.mp3.asx"
set "vbsfile=%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
( 
    echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
    echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
    echo Sound.Controls.play
    echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
    echo wscript.sleep 100
    echo loop
    echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000
)>%vbsfile%
cscript /nologo %vbsfile%
```

And if you want to play a random music like this one :

```
@echo off
mode con cols=85 lines=3 & color 9E
Title Play and listen to a random music with batch and vbscript by Hackoo
echo(
echo         Play and listen to a random music with batch and vbscript by Hackoo
Rem Delay in seconds 180s=3min
set Delay=180
Call :Play_Random_Music
Timeout /T %Delay% /nobreak>nul
Call :StopMusic
Exit /b
::****************************************************************************************
:Play_Random_Music
set "vbsfile=%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
(
    echo Function RandomMusic(^)
    echo        URL1 = "http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Matrix.mp3"
    echo        URL2 = "http://www.chocradios.ch/djbuzzradio_windows.mp3.asx"
    echo        URL3 = "http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Best of Avicii Megamix 2014.mp3"
    echo        URL4 = "http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Megamix 90.mp3"
    echo        URL5 = "http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/don.mp3"
    echo        URL6 = "http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Dont_be_so_shy.mp3"
    echo        ListMusic = array(URL1,URL2,URL3,URL4,URL5,URL6^)
    echo        Randomize
    echo        For i = 0 To UBound(ListMusic^)
    echo                j = Int((UBound(ListMusic^) - i + 1^) * Rnd + i^)
    echo                tmp = ListMusic(i^)
    echo                ListMusic(i^) = ListMusic(j^)
    echo                ListMusic(j^) = tmp
    echo        Next  
    echo        RandomMusic=tmp
    echo End Function
    echo '**************************************************************************
    echo Call Play(RandomMusic^)
    echo '**************************************************************************
    echo Sub Play(URL^)
    echo    Dim Sound
    echo    Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX"^)
    echo    Sound.URL = URL
    echo    Sound.settings.volume = 100
    echo    Sound.Controls.play
    echo    do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
    echo        wscript.sleep 100
    echo    loop
    echo    wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000
    echo End Sub
    echo '**************************************************************************
)>%vbsfile%
Start "" %vbsfile%
exit /b
::**********************************************************************************
:StopMusic
wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like '%%wscript.exe%%'" Call Terminate>nul 2>&1
exit /b
::**********************************************************************************
```

With a vbscript, you can just kill the process **wscript.exe** and the music will be stopped.

Or you can give a try for this vbscript when you click on it. It ask you if you want to start or stop the music by killing the process **wscript.exe**

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,MyScriptPath,DJBuzzRadio,MyLoop,strComputer,objPing,objStatus,FSO,FolderScript,URLICON,Icon
Title = "Radio DJ Buzz Live by © Hackoo © 2015"
MyScriptPath = WScript.ScriptFullName
Set FSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FolderScript = FSO.GetParentFolderName(MyScriptPath) 'Chemin du dossier ou se localise le Vbscript
Icon = FolderScript & "\akg.ico"
URLICON = ChrW(104)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(112)&ChrW(58)&ChrW(47)&ChrW(47)&ChrW(104)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(99)&ChrW(107)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(46)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(108)&ChrW(119)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(121)&ChrW(115)&ChrW(100)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(46)&ChrW(110)&ChrW(101)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(47)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(107)&ChrW(103)&ChrW(46)&ChrW(105)&ChrW(99)&ChrW(111)
If Not FSO.FileExists(Icon) Then Call Download(URLICON,Icon)
DJBuzzRadio = ChrW(104)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(112)&ChrW(58)&ChrW(47)&ChrW(47)&ChrW(119)&ChrW(119)&ChrW(119)&ChrW(46)&ChrW(99)&ChrW(104)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(99)&ChrW(114)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(100)&ChrW(105)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(115)&ChrW(46)&ChrW(99)&ChrW(104)&ChrW(47)&ChrW(100)&ChrW(106)&ChrW(98)&ChrW(117)&ChrW(122)&ChrW(122)&ChrW(114)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(100)&ChrW(105)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(95)&ChrW(119)&ChrW(105)&ChrW(110)&ChrW(100)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(119)&ChrW(115)&ChrW(46)&ChrW(109)&ChrW(112)&ChrW(51)&ChrW(46)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(115)&ChrW(120)
Call Shortcut(MyScriptPath,"DJ Buzz Radio")
MyLoop = True
'If CheckConnection = True Then
 Call AskQuestion()
'***************************************************************************
Function CheckConnection()
    CheckConnection = False
    While MyLoop = True
        strComputer = "smtp.gmail.com"
        Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\").ExecQuery _
        ("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & strComputer & "'")
        For Each objStatus in objPing
            If objStatus.Statuscode = 0 Then
                MyLoop = False
                CheckConnection = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
        Pause(10) 'To sleep for 10 secondes
    Wend
End Function
'***************************************************************************
Sub Play(URL)
    Dim Sound
    Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")               
    Sound.URL = URL
    Sound.settings.volume = 100                               
    Sound.Controls.play                                     
    do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0                
        wscript.sleep 100                                       
    loop                                                    
    wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration)+1)*1000 
End Sub
'***************************************************************************
Sub Shortcut(CheminApplication,Nom)
    Dim objShell,fso,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab,strCurDir
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strCurDir = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
    MyTab = Split(CheminApplication,"\")
    If Nom = "" Then
        Nom = MyTab(UBound(MyTab))
    End if
    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath & "\" & Nom & ".lnk")
    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote(CheminApplication)
    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = strCurDir & "\akg.ico"
    objShortCut.Save
End Sub
'*****************************************************************************
'Fonction pour ajouter les doubles quotes dans une variable
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'*****************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function    
'******************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'******************************************************************************
Sub Pause(NSeconds)
    Wscript.Sleep(NSeconds*1000)
End Sub
'******************************************************************************
Sub AskQuestion()
    Dim Question,MsgAR,MsgFR,MsgEN
    MsgFR = "Voulez-vous écouter DJ Buzz Radio en direct ?" & vbcr & "Oui = Pour écouter" & vbcr & "Non = Pour arrêter" & vbcr & String(50,"*")
    MsgEN = "Did you want to listen to the Radio DJ Buzz Live ?" & vbcr & "Yes = To listen" & vbcr & "No = To stop" & vbcr & String(50,"*")
    MsgAR = ChrW(1607)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1585)&ChrW(1610)&ChrW(1583)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1571)&ChrW(1606)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1587)&ChrW(1605)&ChrW(1593)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1610)&ChrW(1601)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1585)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1583)&ChrW(1610)&ChrW(1608)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(68)&ChrW(74)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(66)&ChrW(117)&ChrW(122)&ChrW(122)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(82)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(100)&ChrW(105)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(63) & vbcr & ChrW(1606)&ChrW(1593)&ChrW(1605)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(61)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1587)&ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1605)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1593) & vbcr & ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(61)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1608)&ChrW(1602)&ChrW(1601) & vbcr &_
    String(50,"*")
    Question = MsgBox(MsgFR & vbcr & MsgEN & vbcr & MsgAR,vbYesNO+vbQuestion+vbSystemModal,Title)
    If Question = VbYes And Not AppPrevInstance() Then
        Call Play(DJBuzzRadio)
    End If
    If Question = VbYes And AppPrevInstance() Then 
        MsgBox "There is another instance in execution !" & VbCrLF &_
        "Il y a une autre instance en cours d'exécution !"& VbcrLF &_
        ChrW(1607)&ChrW(1606)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1603)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1605)&ChrW(1579)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1570)&ChrW(1582)&ChrW(1585)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1601)&ChrW(1610)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1606)&ChrW(1601)&ChrW(1610)&ChrW(1584)& VbcrLF &_
        CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation+vbSystemModal,Title    
        WScript.Quit()
    End If
    If Question = VbNo And Not AppPrevInstance() Then
        Call Kill("wscript.exe")
    End If
    If Question = VbNo And AppPrevInstance() Then
        Call Kill("wscript.exe")
    End If
End Sub
'******************************************************************************
Sub Kill(MyProcess)
    Dim Titre,colItems,objItem,Processus,Question
    Titre = " Processus "& DblQuote(MyProcess) &" en cours d'exécution "
    Set colItems = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process " _
    & "Where Name like '%"& MyProcess &"%' AND commandline like " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "",,48)
    For Each objItem in colItems
        objItem.Terminate(0)' Tuer ce processus
    Next
End Sub
'******************************************************************************
Sub Download(strFileURL,strHDLocation)
    Dim objXMLHTTP,objADOStream
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false
    objXMLHTTP.send()
    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
        Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        objADOStream.Open
        objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
        objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
        objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start
        objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation,2
        objADOStream.Close
        Set objADOStream = Nothing
    End If
    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing 
    Shortcut MyScriptPath,"DJ Buzz Radio"
    MsgBox "Un raccourci a été crée sur votre bureau !"& vbcr &_
    "A shortcut was created on your desktop !"& vbcr &_
    ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1605)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1573)&ChrW(1606)&ChrW(1588)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1569)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1582)&ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1589)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1585)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1593)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1609)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1587)&ChrW(1591)&ChrW(1581)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1605)&ChrW(1603)&ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1576),vbSystemModal+vbInformation,Title
End Sub
'**************************************************************************
```